# Add terms for a specific role not working

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I want to add permission to add new term in Vocabulary. I have used [vppr](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr) and [Taxonomy access fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix) but not worked.

Comment: Did u rebuild permission ??

Comment: Yes using admin/reports/status/rebuild url.

Comment: I have tested this with a clean drupal it working fine, I think some other module overwrite this permission.